# How to connect a device running Phonegap with a server using jquery ajax and JSON?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, cordova

Client Side: This is my index.html which is in my Phonegap project.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script charset="utf&minus;8" type="text/javascript">
        function connect(e) {
            var term = {
                button: e
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/reply.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: term,
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function(jqXHR, text_status, strError) {
                    alert("no connection");
                },
                timeout: 60000,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#result").html("");
                    for (var i in data) {
                        $("#result").append("<li>" + data[i] + "</li>");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <center><b>Bikes or Cars</b>
    </center>
    <center>
        <input onclick="connect(this.value)" type="button" value="cars" />
    </center>
    <center>
        <input onclick="connect(this.value)" type="button" value="bikes" />
    </center>
    <center><b>Results</b>
    </center>
    <ul id="result"></ul>
</body>
```

This is my Server Side (reply.php)

```
<?php
$choice =$_POST["button"];
$cars = array("Mercedes", "BMW" , "Ferrari");
$bikes = array("Ducaite", "Royal Enfield" , "Harley Davidson");
if($choice == "cars") print json_encode($cars);
else print json_encode($bikes);
?>
```

My Problem is, that I don't get the results. What I have tried: First of all, running the phonegap project (client side) is not a problem. Then I placed the "reply.php" in my htdocs (using XAMPP) and the apache is also started, but I don't get the results of my call. Have anyone an idea ?

Comment: You aren't loading Jquery before that script.  Need jquery to use $.ajax.  Or perhaps put that function under app.initialize();  if thats where jquery is being loaded\

Comment: Where localhost? Your app running in device, server is deploy in PC. Device and PC is different. Then device no understand where localhost in PC. Change localhost by ip address or absolute domain

Answer (score 0):

I would try this....

```
function connect(e)
    {
      $.post('http://localhost/reply.php',{button:e},function(data){
        $("#result").html("");
         for(var i in data){
          $("#result").append("<li>"+data[i]+"</li>");
         }
      },"jsonp");
    }
```

But it also appears that you aren't loading jquery before this script is initialized??  Jquery needs to be loaded before using $.ajax, or $.post.  That could be your problem right there

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
</script>
// Possibly put JQUERY HERE if its not included/referenced in any of the above js files
<script type="text/javascript">
    function connect(e) {
        $.post('http://localhost/reply.php',{button:e},function(data){
        $("#result").html("");
         for(var i in data){
          $("#result").append("<li>"+data[i]+"</li>");
         }
      },"jsonp");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. You mean:                                  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>   ?

Answer (score 0):

For local testing an using the same network change

```
url: 'http://localhost/reply.php',
```

to:

```
url: 'http://YOUR_SERVER_IP_HERE/reply.php',
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved, thanks everyone. I tried this on the emulator and also on the smartphone device and it works.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <title>Hello World</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
    </script>


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function connect(e) {
        $.post('http://www.indiageeks.in/tutorials/reply.php',{button:e},function(data){
        $("#result").html("");
         for(var i in data){
          $("#result").append("<li>"+data[i]+"</li>");
         }
      },"json");
    }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
        document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log("onDeviceReady");
    }

    // Handle the online event
    //
    function onOnline() {
        console.log("onOnline");
    }

    function onOffline() {
        console.log("onOffline");
    }

    </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="onLoad()">

    <center><b>Bikes or Cars</b></center>
    <center><input onclick="connect(this.value)" type="button" value="cars" /></center>
    <center><input onclick="connect(this.value)" type="button" value="bikes" /></center>
    <center><b>Results</b></center>
    <center><ul id="result"></ul></center>

    </body>
</html>
```